# How to offset an alert on pine editor (TradingView)

Tags: offset, pine-script

I need some help to offset my alert by 1
I'm able to offset the arrow (plotted) but I can't figure out how to offset the actual alert so it comes on the next candle (so the cross is confirmed)

```
tavg = tos == 1 ? avg(a,avg) : avg(b,avg)
tavgi = tosi == 1 ? avg(ai,avgi) : avg(bi,avgi)

enterLong = crossover(tavgi, tavg)
enterShort = crossunder(tavgi, tavg)

alertcondition(enterLong, title='Long', message='long tradesymbol=EURUSD')
alertcondition(enterShort, title='Short', message='short tradesymbol=EURUSD')
```

How to add an offset=1 to enterLong and enterShort

I tried

```
enterLong = crossover(tavgi, tavg)
barcolor(color=enterLong ? blue : na, offset=1)
alertcondition(condition=enterLong,
     message="long tradesymbol=EURUSD")
     
enterShort = crossunder(tavgi, tavg)
barcolor(color=enterShort ? orange : na, offset=1)
alertcondition(condition=enterShort,
     message="short tradesymbol=EURUSD")
```

but it obviously only offset only the barcolor not the alert :(

Sorry I can't put the whole code but if you have an idea it would be highly appreciated thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done via the history operator `[]`, checking the condition on the previous bar:

```
alertcondition(enterLong[1], title='Long', message='long tradesymbol=EURUSD')
alertcondition(enterShort[1], title='Short', message='short tradesymbol=EURUSD')
```